How to calculate elapsed time between bike rides spanning multiple days in a spreadsheet?
I'm working with a dataset containing information about bike sharing rides. The data includes the start time and end time of each ride. I want to calculate the average time between bike rides for a given month.
The challenge I'm facing is that some rides start on one day and end on the next day. For example, if a ride starts at 11:00 PM and ends at 1:00 AM the following day, calculating the elapsed time using a simple formula like "end time minus start time" results in a negative value.
I initially tried using a formula like =EndTime - StartTime to calculate the elapsed time between rides. However, this approach doesn't work correctly when the end time is earlier than the start time due to the rides spanning across different days.
I also considered adding an extra day to the end time if it's less than the start time, but this solution isn't efficient when dealing with a large dataset, as I would need to manually identify and adjust the formula for each case.

Minimal runnable code?

How would you know, for example, given a start time of 11:00pm and an end time of 01:00am that there's just 3hrs between them? If that's all the information you have (i.e., you don't have the date(s)) then you can never accurately calculate the interval. Without date information the interval might be 27hrs or 51hrs etc. If you do know the dates then take a look at the datetime module

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can calculate the difference of two datetime objects:
from datetime import datetime

# datetime in string format
start = '2024/06/14 20:00:00.00000'
end = '2024/6/17 02:00:00.00000'

# convert string to datetime
start_t = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
end_t = datetime.strptime(end, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

# difference between datetime in timedelta
delta = end_t - start_t
print(f"The time delta is: {delta}")

Output:
The time delta is: 2 days, 6:00:00


Why would you import timedelta when it's already available as part of datetime? Also, there is nothing in the OP to suggest that dates are available - only times
